# Entity framwork, POCO, create your own DB by code?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, poco

I am interested to know is there are any reasonable ways to create your own DB, `CREATE MyDatabase`, `CREATE Table1` inside Entity `DbContext`, mabye `InitializeDatabase` method?
I know EF 4.1 with POCO will do it for me, but now seems that if I want generate some events during DB initialize(see edit), I probably want generate DB in my code.

Say if I want to report the DB creation progress to the end user, I need create Database ant Tables in my code, in order to to that, I need figure out how to to create Database(not table) inside my code.

I've tried:

```
public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
{

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Query to create table");
}
```

But the problem is that I need create the Database first in order to create tables, but how to do that? Or there are better ways to do what I want?

**EDIT:**

Yes, I know POCO will do that for me automatically, but unfortunately, seems that I do need/want create Database and Tables by my code with POCO, the reason is that I want show the progress during DB creation/initialize phrase? The only way I can come out is to create Database and create tables though my own code and generate events after each table been created.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework will attempt to create the database you configured in the connection string. Just make sure that the user that connects to the server has rights to create a database.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks like Entity Framework Code First.

You can create a Database and / Tables in the Model Builder `Seed` method if you want.

If your only goal is to report to the user the progress, you don't need to create the database using your own queries. You can do this using the `ModelBuilder` `OnModelCreating`.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I know POCO will do that for me automatically, but unfortunately, seems that I do need create Database and Tables by myself even with POCO

Nope!  At least, not if you're using Entity Framework 4 *(The version shipped with .Net 4.0, which requires Visual Studio 2010.  VS 2008 cannot use .Net 4.0)*.

It's called **Code-First development**.  Basically, you write your data classes, and Entity Framework infers the database structure automatically based on the class relationships, property-names, and some optional EF-specific attributes.  It then creates the database for you automatically *(though support for automatic migrations is minimal... [for now](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx))*.

There are some simple tutorials on Code First [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have POCO working fine, and by default it did generate DB structure for me. Now my problem is that if I do want generate DB and table myself as I need generate events after each table been generated, how can I do that?